# Change color of icon on condition

Tags: css, design-patterns, web, responsive-design

I am preparing a signup form for my website. I am able to check if the username typed by the user is already there or not. But I want to change the color of the icon of the username that I've given to green if there are no such name taken and to green if already exist.
How can I do that?

Similar to what happens in this website https://www.hackerrank.com/signup

PS. I am a newbie. Do explain in detail. If possible even with some example codes.

**EDIT:**

Here is the code that I've used

```
<?php
                 // Ajax calls this code to CHECK the username to execute
if(isset($_POST["usernamecheck"])){
include_once("db_conx.php");
$username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['usernamecheck']);
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysql_query($vaffle); 
$uname_check = $query -> num_rows;
if (strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 16) {
    echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">3 - 16 characters only</strong>';
    exit();
}
if (is_numeric($username[0])) {
    echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">Usernames must begin with a letter</strong>';
    exit();
}

if ($uname_check < 1) {
    echo '<strong style="color:#009900;">' . $username . ' is OK</strong>';
    exit();
} else {
    echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">' . $username . ' is taken</strong>';
    exit();
}
}
?>
```

Form Code:

```
<div class="formgroup">
            <i class="icon-user"></i>
        <input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Choose an Username" data-content="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" onblur="checkusername()" onkeyup="restrict('username')" maxlength="16">
        <span id="unamestatus"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="formgroup">
            <i class="icon-mail"></i>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="mail" value="" placeholder="Your Email Id" data-content="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('email')" maxlength="88">
    </div>
    <div class="formgroup">
            <i class="icon-lock"></i>
        <input id="pass1" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Choose a password" data-content="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
    </div>

    <div class="formgroup">
            <i class="icon-lock"></i>
        <input id="pass2" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" data-content="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
    </div>
```

Can I modify this code in anyway to get my desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is to validate that the field isn't blank (and, well, valid) and unfortunately you need to do this part with javascript. To change the icon / label, I recommend you apply these changes by using javascript to add a "valid" class after you're sure the field isn't empty.

You didn't show us your current code, but if you have a simple form like

```
<label for="username"> <i class="icon-user" alt="Username"></i> </label>
<input id="username" type="text">
```

which uses an icon for the label, your css might look like

```
label .icon-user:before {
  color: gray;
  content: "u"; // ... or whatever the corresponding symbol
  font-family: 'icomoon'; // assuming you're using an icon font      
} 

label.valid .icon-user:before {
  color: green;
}
```

As the user moves on to the next field, your javascript checks to see whether the preceding field is valid, and if so adds the "valid" class to the label. You can even create an invalid class where the icon is red. Of course, if you're using a sprite or a graphic, you just swap-in the appropriate styles for the .valid class.

Does this help?